Copying Large files between Jenkins Nodes
In jenkins, I have a pipeline file in which I build the code on one node and then I would like to transfer the binaries to another node and execute the binaries there. stash/unstash could have been an option but it works for smaller files. So, I would like to achieve this in one jenkins pipeline job instead of creating multiple jobs.
node("Compute instance 1") {
        stage('Clone') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage('Run system_info') {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
                cat /proc/cpuinfo
            '''
        }
        stage('Run configure') {
                CONFIGURE_COMMANDS
        }
        stage('Run build') {
                BUILD_COMMANDS
        }
    }
}
//Transfer binaries to following compute instance
node('Compute instance 2'){
        stage('Run system_info') {
            sh'''#!/bin/bash
                cat /proc/cpuinfo
            '''
        }
        stage('Run test') {
            RUN_EXECUTION_COMMANDS
        }
    }
}

I tried using external workspace manager but it creates a folder on my compute instance but does not transfer files in it. My Jenkins settings for external workspace management are such that, I created a folder $HOME/jenkins_mountpoint in Jenkins master and referenced the same mountpoint path in my node settings. Following is my pipeline file for external workspace builder.
def extWorkspace = exwsAllocate diskPoolId: 'diskpool1'
node("Compute instance 1") {
    exws (extWorkspace){
        stage('Clone') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage('Run system_info') {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
                cat /proc/cpuinfo
            '''
        }
        stage('Run configure') {
            CONFIGURE_COMMANDS
        }
        stage('Run build') {
            BUILD_COMMANDS
        }
    }
}
node('Compute instance 2'){
    exws (extWorkspace){
        //Insuring that we are in RISC-V instance
        stage('Run system_info') {
            sh'''#!/bin/bash
                cat /proc/cpuinfo
            '''
        }
        stage('Run test') {
            EXECUTION_COMMANDS
        }
    }
}


Have you considered archiveArtifacts/copyArtifacts? Since you mentioned stash you probably don't mind copying files twice - to the controller first and then to another agent, but if that's an issue you could probably get away with one copy directly between the agents. It would be much more complex though.
